# overflow:scroll not showing a disabled scroll on Chrome Mobile

Tags: html, css, mobile-chrome

When I set `overflow: scroll` to a div, I'm expecting to have a scrollbar even when the content doesn't scroll (for design purposes)

but when there's no need to scroll, chrome mobile hides the scrollbar anyway.

```css
.div-scroll{
  background-color: red;
  height: 300px;
  overflow-y: scroll;
}
.div-inner {
  background-color: blue;
  height: 200px;
}
```

```html
<div class="div-scroll">
  <div class="div-inner">
  </div>
</div>
```

I'd like to show a disabled scroll on Chrome Mobile when the content doesn't scroll, or at least a way to know from pure CSS that it doesn't scroll, to avoid using `width: calc(100% - 17px);`

[Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/2uf54kgm/2)

Comment: fiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/2uf54kgm/2/

Answer (score 3, accepted):

On webkit browsers to have a permanent scrollbar you can use the use the `::webkit-scrollbar` `::webkit-scrollbar-thumb` properties and customize them.

Refer following code:

```css
.filter-list {
  width: 75px;
  height: 100px;
  overflow: auto;
}

.filter-list::-webkit-scrollbar,
.filter-list::-webkit-scrollbar,
.filter-list::-webkit-scrollbar {
  -webkit-appearance: none;
  width: 15px;
}

.filter-list::-webkit-scrollbar-thumb,
.filter-list::-webkit-scrollbar-thumb,
.filter-list::-webkit-scrollbar-thumb {
  border-radius: 4px;
  background-color: lightgray;
  box-shadow: 0 0 1px rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.5);
}
```

```html
<div class="filter-list">
  <div> Hello </div>
  <div> World </div>
  <div> Hello </div>
  <div> World </div>
  <div> Hello </div>
  <div> World </div>
  <div> Hello </div>
  <div> World </div>
  <div> Hello </div>
  <div> World </div>
</div>
```

Comment: I don't want to remake the whole scrollbar, I just want to force the width to 17px, but when I use `.div-scroll::-webkit-scrollbar { width: 17px; }`, it deletes the scroll.

Comment: Might be because the width is not sufficient. Check edited answer where I have modified width of scrollbar.

Comment: How can I keep browser defaults and just change the width?

Comment: You cannot customize the inbuilt browser's scrollbar. What webkit browsers provide you with is to play around with your own css with the `-webkit-scrollbar`.